# Python Polars: how to join with lazyframes?

Tags: python, chunks, python-polars

I am trying to join two big parquets using lazyframe, but it's not possible due their size (polars collapses).

Then I was thinking about using iter_slices, but it' doesn't work with lazyframes.
What would be a good solution for this?
What's the usefulness of iter_slices if must be a Dataframe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset doesn't fit into memory, you can try adding a `filter` or a `limit` behind the `join` node and materialize via `collect(streaming=True)`. This will try to execute the query out of core.

If the result dataset doesn't fit into memory, you can stream it directly to disk using `sink_parquet` or `sink_ipc`.